# How to delete morphable data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I delete my product images that are morph to that product won't get deleted.

`controller`

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    if(!empty($product->image)){
        Storage::delete($product->image);
    }

    $images = Gallery::where('imageable_id', $product->id)->get(); //i get the images but it won't delete them
    if(!empty($images)){
        Storage::delete($images);
    }

    $product->delete();
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

**any idea?**

Comment: do they delete only from storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't delete the records from the table. Only delete them from the storage. try something like this.

```
$product->image()->delete();
```

Edit

To delete the files from folder, you can do something like this.

```
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($images); $x++)
    {
       $file= $image->your_file_path;
       $filename = public_path().'/uploads_folder/'.$file;
       \File::delete($filename);
    }
```

complete code,

```
$images = Gallery::where('imageable_id', $product->id)->get(); //i get the images but it won't delete them
if(!empty($images)){

for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($images); $x++)
 {
   $file= $image->your_file_path;
   $filename = public_path().'/uploads_folder/'.$file;
   \File::delete($filename);
 }

 $product->image()->delete();
}
```

Comment: it now delete database but files are still in my folder

Comment: give me the column names of your gallery table

Comment: `id | file | imageable_type | imageable_id |  alt | created_at | updated_at`

Comment: so i don't use `$product->image()->delete();` any more?

Comment: No. You need to use that also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201479/discussion-between-dilusha-dasanayaka-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will solve the morph delete problem

```
$product->image()->delete();
```

Comment: yes but then it didn't delete files.now plus using this simple code i added extra lines `thanks to dilusha_dasanayaka` to delete actual files as well.